# Counting distinct elements in Django ArrayField

Tags: django

I have a model defined by

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
```

I would like a way to efficiently grab the count of each distinct element in my tags ArrayField. I put together this piece of code to do try to do that.

```py
Model.objects.annotate(elems=Func(F('tags'), function='unnest')).values_list('elems', flat=True).annotate(c=Count('elems'))
```

But it returns an error

```
...aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
LINE 1: ...COUNT(unnest("...
                 ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

Any ideas on how to make this query work?

**Edit**

This is the SQL that Django's ORM generates.

```sql
SELECT unnest("model"."tags") AS "elems", COUNT(unnest("model"."tags")) AS "c" FROM "model" GROUP BY unnest("model"."tags");
```

Comment: Could you please post a full database query ?

Comment: Added an edit. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This query worked for me:

```
select unnest(tags) as tag, count(tags) from model group by tag;
```

I think this ORM query gives the same result:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Count

Model.objects.annotate(tag=Func(F('tags'), function='unnest')).values('tag').order_by('tag').annotate(count=Count('id')).values_list('tag', 'count')
```

I have created the following table and populated with sample values:

```
create table model(
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    tags text[]
);

insert into model(name, tags) values ('a', array['a', 'b', 'c']);
insert into model(name, tags) values ('b', array['b', 'b', 'c']);

select unnest(tags) as tag, count(tags) from model group by tag;

+---+-----+
|tag|count|
+---+-----+
|c  |2    |
|a  |1    |
|b  |3    |
+---+-----+
```